# iOS navbar is not translucent enough

Tags: ios, swift, navigationbar

could someone point me in the right direction to achieve a similar translucent effect as shown on Netflix's navbar.

I've been trying many things, however my nav bar is stays too dark and doesn't let enough light through, thus I can barely see any colors behind it when scrolling.

Is there any way to increase the amount of light allowed through the view, thus making the nav bar 'more' translucent? 
Any advice appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've done it in the past:

In your ApplicationDelegate, add to `func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool` these lines:

```
 let navbarAppearance = UINavigationBar.appearance()
 navbarAppearance.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
 navbarAppearance.shadowImage = UIImage()
 navbarAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.1)
```

Just change the color and vary the alpha component to increase or decrease the transparency, as desired.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sadly this does not do it because transparency != translucent.

Comment: Oh, apologies - I thought I read transparency instead of translucency :)

How are you adding the blur effect to the nav bar? 
It is possible to change the alpha of the UIVisualEffectView, and this should help.

Comment: yeah, thats how i ended up solving it and made it look just like the netflix bar. I used the uivisualeffect dark blur on top of the tableview as a 'navbar'